# Picasso: Cache and redirected URLs

Tags: android, picasso

Here's what I currently understand:

1. I load http://www.example.com/imageA.png into my imageView using Picasso.
2. Picasso downloads imageA.png and in simple terms, caches it internally as "http://www.example.com/imageA.png".
3. I go offline, open my app, and Picasso tries to load http://www.example.com/imageA.png into my imageView again. It loads the image from the cache. I can see imageA even when my network isn't working.

This is all fine and dandy.

Say for example http://www.example.com/imageA.png now redirects to http://www.example.com/imageB.png and I repeat steps 1 and 2.

This time, I believe, Picasso caches it as http://www.example.com/imageB.png and therefore when I open my app in offline mode, I don't see imageA because it's cached as imageB.

Am I right?

Is there a way to force Picasso to cache it as its original URL?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can add a `stableKey` to the request with the `Request.Builder()`
https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Request.Builder.html#stableKey-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thanks @dumazy, I tried that but it still doesn't work. The image goes throught a custom `Transformation` though, does Picasso still use the stableKey, or uses the one defined in the custom `Transformation`?

Comment: Have you tried checki'g the stableKeys in debug mode? Android Studio allows you to dive into decompiled code of dependencies where you can place breakpoints. This should give you more info

Answer (score 0):

Picasso manages memory cache only, so stableKey is only about that. Disk cache is managed by OkHttp. It's behaviour cannot be changed because com.squareup.okhttp.Cache is a final class.